# materalizecss datepicker dynamic options

Tags: jquery, materialize

I have 2 date picketers using `materalizecss`
start_date and end_date
I want when I change start_date then I need to change few **options** of end_date at **runtime** on the **basis of selected start date** like (`max_date`, `default_date`/`selected_date`...)

```
 $('#txtEndDate').datepicker({
  format:"yyyy-mm-dd", 
  showClearBtn:true,
  setDefaultDate:true
});


$('#txtStartDate').datepicker({
  //defaultDate:expDate,
  format:"yyyy-mm-dd",
  showClearBtn:true,
  onClose(){ 
    var reminderDate = new Date($('#txtStartDate').val());
    var grace_days=  60;//from another input
    if(grace_days >0 ){  
      reminderDate.setDate(expDate.getDate() - grace_days);
      //$('#endDate').datepicker('gotoDate',reminderDate); 
      //$('#endDate').datepicker('setDate',reminderDate);  
      //$('#endDate').datepicker('option','maxDate',reminderDate);//this not working  
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is run the #endDate initialisation during the onClose of startDate:

```
$('#startDate').datepicker({
    format:"yyyy-mm-dd",
  showClearBtn:true,
  onClose(){ 
    var reminderDate = new Date($('#startDate').val());
    var grace_days=  60;//from another input
    if(grace_days >0 ){  

      $('#endDate').datepicker({
          format:"yyyy-mm-dd", 
          showClearBtn:true,
          defaultDate: reminderDate,
          setDefaultDate:true,
          maxDate:reminderDate
      });

    }
  }
  });
```

Check this codepen:

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/abOJovW

Note I had to take out reference to expDate because it was never declared and was breaking the function. You should be able to tweak this to get what you need :)